# Getting error when executing Localtunnel on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, localtunnel

I've just installed localtunnel on a Ubuntu 16.04 using the command `sudo npm install -g localtunnel`, but getting an error when try to execute it.

```
$ lt --port 8080
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/bin/lt.js:8
const { version } = require('../package');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

```
$ npm -version
3.5.2
```

```
$ lt --help
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/bin/lt.js:8
const { version } = require('../package');
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

How to get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

try running

lt -h "https://serverless.social" -p 8080

it should work

for more information: https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/344

Comment: same error. The problem is with the lt. Even this command `lt --help` give me the same error.

Comment: did you get an error while  running,

npm install -g localtunnel

Answer (score -1):

try This

But I have debian

> ## /etc/apt/sources.list :
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
> deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
> non-free deb http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
> non-free  deb-src http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
> non-free
>
> apt-get clean
>
> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get -f install
>
> dpkg--configure -a
>
> apt-get install --force-yes  apt-transport-https lsb-release
>
> curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
>
> apt-get install -y nodejs
>
> npm install -g localtunnel
>
> ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
>
> lt --port 80*

Works for me